# Redirect to custom page for Users who do not have webpages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, webserver

There are many users on my server who do not have webpages; they have neither made index.html files nor given any permissions. Their pages show "403 Forbidden". For example, pages like

`www.example.com/~user`

show

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /~user on this server.
```

I have already set .htaccess so that 403 errors are redirected to a custom page. However, these pages are not redirecting to the custom page.

How do I fix this?

Edit: My .htaccess file is

```
ErrorDocument 404 error/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 error/403.php
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Please show the .htaccess file that you are using to redirect the 403 errors. Otherwise it is nearly impossible to tell how to fix this.

Comment: I have added the .htaccess file. Thanks.